# HTC Desire 616 hard-bricked (dead) after format all + download in sp falsh tool

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, formatting

Recently I have used SP flash tool for flash htc desire 616. I flashed successfully. But I am unable to start the OS. So once again i done "format all+download". But now my phone completely dead. Please help any one how to write NVRAM files (including factory logo and imei no). But still, i am able to flash the mobile using SP flash tool. But mobile not getting ON. Please help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The dead state of a smartphone is actually because of corrupted firmware files.
either the rom your are flashing is corrupted or the flashing process is interrupted whatever is the problem. try flashing with some other flashing tool and make sure you are flashing the right rom for your smartphone...

and about factory logo and imei no. factory logo is inbuilt in the rom your are flashing if it is official..and for the imei all android roms have modem binaries which are responsible for networking and imei related operations..

Can you tell me about your smartphone.?

Comment: i tried using a different flash file but it's in the same position (dead).